# r: call name of list object in for-loop (phyloseq object)

Tags: r, phyloseq

I'm trying to create a for-loop to analyse a big phyloseq object with different subsets. I'm trying to call the name of each list object for each iteration so I can save the outcomes with the different names.

Making the list of phyloseq objects

```
subset1 <- excluded_data %>%
  subset_samples(Animal == "Chronic Stress" & Sex == "Male" & Time.Point =="After")

subset2 <- excluded_data %>%
  subset_samples(Animal == "Chronic Stress" & Sex == "Male")
                 
listofsubsets <- list(list1 = subset1, list2= subset2)
```

When I call this:

```
names(listofsubsets)

names(listofsubsets)
[1] "list1" "list2"
```

Great.

So I move on to my for loop:

```
for(l in listofsubsets[1:2]) {
  
  print(l)
  
#do analysis stuff

#example use for name

NMDSname <- paste(NAMEOFITERATION, "NMDS_results", ".txt", sep = "_")

}
```

It uses `l` perfectly for the downstream analysis, because

```
> l
phyloseq-class experiment-level object
otu_table()   OTU Table:         [ 39751 taxa and 19 samples ]
sample_data() Sample Data:       [ 19 samples by 9 sample variables ]
tax_table()   Taxonomy Table:    [ 39751 taxa by 7 taxonomic ranks ]
```

But it doesn't call the name.

```
>   print(names(listofsubsets$l))
NULL
```

Thanks!

Comment: If you need the list names in your loop, iterate over the list names and subset the list inside the loop. In your code, `l` is the list element and you obviously can't subset a list with its elements. Furthermore, study `help("$")` to learn the second reason why it can't work.

Comment: @Roland can you give me an example of what you mean? because what I've come up with means that I have to rename the variables for every iteration in the downstream analysis...  before, it worked perfectly pulling the phyloseq object from l, it's just the name that's missing.

Comment: `for(i in names(listofsubsets[1:2])) {l <- listofsubsets[[i]]; print(l); print(i)}`